# Как параллельные потоки можно останавливать и запускать относительно их общей переменной?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Можно ли сделать так что бы потоки шли параллельно, но при этом при определённом условии они бы могли останавливать и запускать друг друга. Просто если их делать синхронизированными они идут по очереди, а без синхронизации не поставить wait() notify() Я поставил слипы, и поток получился зацикленным. Вместо слипов я хотел бы поставить wait, и что бы после прохождения цикла второго потока он этот wait снимал бы.

```
public class Port extends Runner  {
    private List<Ships> ships;
    static private int portCapacity = 0;
    private int maxPortCapacity = 1000;


   public void uploadDockCargo(){
       int count = 0;
        for (int numberShip = 0; numberShip < ships.size (); numberShip++){
            if (ships.get (numberShip).getShipTarget().equals (ShipTarget.UPLOAD)  ){
                if (portCapacity + ships.get (numberShip).getCapacity () < maxPortCapacity){
                    try {
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep (ships.get (numberShip).getCapacity ());
                        portCapacity += ships.get (numberShip).getCapacity ();
                        System.out.println ("контейнеры выгружены в порт с коробля " + ships.get (numberShip).getName () + " текущая загруженность порта " + portCapacity);

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace ();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    try {
                        numberShip--;
                        System.out.println ("разгрузка невозможна, порт заполнен, ожидайте");
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep (300);
                        if (count < 3){
                            count++;

                        }
                        else {
                            System.out.println ("время ожидания истекло");
                            upload.interrupt ();
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace ();
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
   public void downloadDockCargo()  {
    int count = 0;
       for (int numberShip = 0; numberShip < ships.size (); numberShip++) {
            if (ships.get (numberShip).getShipTarget ().equals (ShipTarget.DOWNLOAD)) {
                if (portCapacity >= ships.get (numberShip).getCapacity ()){
                    try {
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep (ships.get (numberShip).getCapacity ());
                        portCapacity -= ships.get (numberShip).getCapacity ();
                        System.out.println ("контейнеры отгружены на " + ships.get (numberShip).getName () + " текущая загруженность порта" + portCapacity);
                        count = 0;
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace ();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    try {
                        numberShip--;
                        System.out.println ("в порту недостаточно груза, ожидайте");
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep (300);
                        if (count < 3){
                            count++;
                    }
                        else {
                            System.out.println ("время ожидания истекло");
                            download.interrupt ();
                        }

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace ();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public Port(List<Ships> ships) {
        this.ships = ships;
    }
}

package thereads;


import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Runner {
   static Thread download;
   static Thread upload;
       static List<Ships> ships = Arrays.asList (
                new Ships ("Kutuzov", 300, ShipTarget.UPLOAD),
                new Ships ("King of Sea", 400, ShipTarget.DOWNLOAD),
                new Ships ("Alexandr", 300, ShipTarget.UPLOAD),
               new Ships ("Victory", 350, ShipTarget.UPLOAD),
               new Ships ("Lucky", 500, ShipTarget.DOWNLOAD),
               new Ships ("Vicing", 450, ShipTarget.DOWNLOAD)
       );

        public static void main(String[] args)  {

            Port port = new Port (ships);
                 download = new Thread (() -> port.uploadDockCargo ());
                 upload = new Thread (() -> port.downloadDockCargo ());
                download.start ();
                upload.start ();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Тебе надо использовать простейшую блокировку ([ReentrantLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html)), связанную с портом. В дальнейшем будем отталкиваться от того, что в порту в один может происходить только одна операция:

- Поиск места на складе с **возможной** выгрузкой с корабля на склад
- Поиск товара на складе с **возможной** погрузкой со склада на корабль

При этом каждая операция на складе проходит атомарно. Я не буду рассматривать случай, когда возможна параллельная отгрузка/погрузка или же частичная отгрузка/погрузка, т.к. такие системы прогнозирования довольно сложные (и стоят много денег).

Указанная блокировка как раз и будет заниматься оповещением другого потока.

Также хочу заметить, что я не увидел в твоём коде пометок кораблей, которые ранее были загружены/разгружены.

Соответственно, вставив эту блокировку + пометку кораблей на загрузку/разгрузку + ещё немного косметических улучшений, получим примерно следующее:

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class PortTest {

    static List<Ships> ships = Arrays.asList(
            new Ships("Kutuzov", 300, ShipTarget.UPLOAD),
            new Ships("King of Sea", 400, ShipTarget.DOWNLOAD),
            new Ships("Alexandr", 300, ShipTarget.UPLOAD),
            new Ships("Victory", 350, ShipTarget.UPLOAD),
            new Ships("Lucky", 500, ShipTarget.DOWNLOAD),
            new Ships("Vicing", 450, ShipTarget.DOWNLOAD)
    );

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {

        Port port = new Port(ships);
        ExecutorService ex = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        Future<?> uploadRes = ex.submit(port::uploadDockCargo);
        Future<?> downloadRes = ex.submit(port::downloadDockCargo);
        uploadRes.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        downloadRes.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


    }

    enum  ShipTarget {
        UPLOAD, DOWNLOAD
    }

    static class Ships {


        private final String name;
        private final int capacity;
        private final ShipTarget shipTarget;

        public Ships(String name, int capacity, ShipTarget shipTarget) {
            this.name = name;
            this.capacity = capacity;
            this.shipTarget = shipTarget;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public int getCapacity() {
            return capacity;
        }

        public ShipTarget getShipTarget() {
            return shipTarget;
        }
    }

    static class Port {
        private final List<Ships> ships;
        private int portCapacity = 0;
        private final static int MAX_PORT_CAPACITY = 1000;

        private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

        public void uploadDockCargo() {
            List<Ships> thisShips = ships.stream().filter(it -> it.getShipTarget() == ShipTarget.UPLOAD).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
            while (thisShips.size() != 0) {

                Iterator<Ships> iter = thisShips.iterator();
                for (; iter.hasNext(); ) {
                    Ships currentShip = iter.next();
                    lock.lock();
                    try {
                        if (portCapacity + currentShip.getCapacity() < MAX_PORT_CAPACITY) {
                            try {
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(currentShip.getCapacity());
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                throw new RuntimeException(e);
                            }
                            portCapacity += currentShip.getCapacity();
                            iter.remove();
                            System.out.println("контейнеры выгружены в порт с коробля " + currentShip.getName() + " текущая загруженность порта " + portCapacity);

                        }
                    } finally {
                        lock.unlock();
                    }


                }
            }
        }

        public void downloadDockCargo() {
            List<Ships> thisShips = ships.stream().filter(it -> it.getShipTarget() == ShipTarget.DOWNLOAD).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));

            while (thisShips.size() != 0) {
                Iterator<Ships> iter = thisShips.iterator();
                for (; iter.hasNext(); ) {
                    Ships currentShip = iter.next();
                    lock.lock();
                    try {
                        if (portCapacity >= currentShip.getCapacity()) {
                            try {
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(currentShip.getCapacity());
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                throw new RuntimeException(e);
                            }
                            portCapacity -= currentShip.getCapacity();
                            iter.remove();
                            System.out.println("контейнеры отгружены на " + currentShip.getName() + " текущая загруженность порта " + portCapacity);
                        }
                    } finally {
                        lock.unlock();
                    }
                }


            }
        }

        public Port(List<Ships> ships) {
            this.ships = ships;
        }
    }
}
```

Замечу тот факт, что в с указанными данными ты никогда не получишь позитивный результат, т.к. суммарное количество груза, который будет выгружен на склад (300+300+350=950) меньше груза, который должны забрать со склада (400+500+450=1350)

Comment: Спасибо, попробую. Там по заданию, есть несколько гаваней в которых происходит разгрузка\загрузка и в которые заходят корабли. Я сразу выбрал неправильную концепцию судя по репозиториям других, они потоками сделали корабли, а гавани циклами.          
  
 Данные я специально такие указал что бы отловить это условие, иначе потоки просто прошли успешно.

Comment: @АлексейСетько по поводу реализации потоков на кораблях. Это по-сути такое же решение, оно аналогично принципу вытестняющей многопоточности. Каждый поток (корабль) пытается захватить ресурс (порт) и произвести в нём операцию (погрузку/выгрузку), потом освобождает ресурс (порт). Принципиально данное решение почти ничем не будет отличаться от изложенного, разве что порядком погрузки/выгрузки.